# Variable value does not get updated when return-ed

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why an integer isn't being updated. I have added event listeners to specific classes and once I hover over them the index should get updated.

That is not the case. Console log keeps on repeating that Old index: 0, New index is 1. Once I hover the next element it repeats that the Old index is 0 and the New index is 1 (value of index does not get updated).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

```js
var index = 0;
var indexArray = ["1", "2", "3"];

function addListeners() {
  let eListeners = document.querySelectorAll(".eListener");
  for (let i = 0; i < eListeners.length; i++) {
    eListeners[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      indexPlus(index)
    });
  }
}

function indexPlus(index) {
  if (index == 2) {
    console.log("Old index: " + index);
    index = 0;
    console.log("New index: " + index);
    return index;
  } else {
    console.log("Old index: " + index);
    index = index + 1;
    console.log("New index: " + index);
    return index;
  }
}

addListeners();
```

```html
<span class="eListener">Some text1</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text2</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text3</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text4</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text5</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text6</span>
```

Comment: I've tried to not only clearly explain what went wrong in your code, but to also help you improve your general coding approach. Let me know if anything is unclear and feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `indexPlus` function use a different name for your parameter, not `index` as it's already globally defined

```js
var index = 0;
var indexArray = [];

function addListeners() {
  let eListeners = document.querySelectorAll(".eListener");
  for (let i = 0; i < eListeners.length; i++) {
    //indexArray[i] = 0;
    eListeners[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      indexPlus(index)
    });
  }
}

function indexPlus(ind) {
  if (ind == 2) {
    console.log("Old index: " + index);
    index = 0;
    console.log("New index: " + index);
  } else {
    console.log("Old index: " + index);
    index = index + 1;
    console.log("New index: " + index);
  }
}

addListeners();
```

```html
<span class="eListener">Some text1</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text2</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text3</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text4</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text5</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text6</span>
```

Comment: This has gone only half way. Either remove the `return index` statements, or make use of those and instead return and assign `ind`. Also, it's never a good idea to modify globally scoped variables inside a function call.

Comment: Thank you. That cleared it up a little bit. There is still some confusion on my part and I'm a bit embarrassed since this is basic stuff.

Comment: Shouldn't we declare 'ind' somewhere as well? why does console log show updated index values while we only updated ind?

Comment: You are not updating ind here, index is being updated on the basis of ind

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the `indexPlus` function parameter `index`, not your global `index` variable.

To achieve that, you need to **assign** the return value of `indexPlus` to `index` *inside* your listeners. To make that more clear I've renamed the function parameter to `idx`.

Last things: I've shortened your check inside the ìndexPlus` function:

Instead of checking for `2` and then resetting to `0`, and otherwise incrementing, you can make use of the [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder):

```
idx = ++idx % 3;
```

That is a matter of how comfortable you feel with that. There's nothing wrong with your checks staying the way you implemented them.

I've also refactored your index-based loop to a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop which is preferred because it improves readability.

```js
let index = 0;
let eListeners = document.querySelectorAll(".eListener");

function addListeners() {
  for (const eListener of eListeners) {
    eListener.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      index = indexPlus(index)
    });
  }
}

function indexPlus(idx) {
  console.log("Old index: " + idx);
  idx = ++idx % 3;
  console.log("New index: " + idx);
  return idx;
}

addListeners();
```

```html
<span class="eListener">Some text1</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text2</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text3</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text4</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text5</span>
<span class="eListener">Some text6</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. That kind of makes sense. But shouldn't I declare the `idx` somewhere as well?

Comment: You did, when naming your function parameter `idx`. That **is** the declaration. Please don't use the code as shown in the answer you picked, it is bad programming practice to modify global variables inside function calls.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. What I actually wanted was a basic function which would increment the index every time it's run ('function indexPlus(){...}'), so without an input parameter. In this case I assume there is no other way then to modify the global variable from within the function.

Comment: That way you are crippling functions for no reason. Functions are meant to take parameters - use them.